# Express a return value as an "if" condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write in the code that if `$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )` returns false, it shows an image in a div.

maybe something like this:

```
<?php if (condition returns false) { 
echo '<div><img src="image source"></div>'
} ?>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? (apart from using the wrong quotes inside the echo statement) :P

Comment: I'm very new to php (about 1month into studying it), and I don't know how to express the condition inside the "if" brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use your function INSIDE the if statement in PHP:

```
<?php 
if (!wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )) 
{ 
    echo "<div><img src='image source'></div>"
} ?>
```

The `!` flips the if condition so that instead of `if TRUE do...` it becomes `if FALSE do...`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [`!` ("not") operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

```
if (condition)  // Branches when `condition` is true
if (!condition) // Branches when `condition` is false
```

`!` inverts a boolean value. That is, `!TRUE` is `FALSE`, and `!FALSE` is `TRUE`.

If you're dealing with a condition where you've used `==`, rather than using `!` you would use `!=`. So for instance, if you want to invert this:

```
if ($a == $b)
```

you would **not** do this:

```
if (!$a == $b) // <== WRONG
```

you would do this:

```
if ($a != $b)
```

this is also valid, but frequently more convoluted than is necessary:

```
if (!($a == $b)) // (note the parentheses so that ! applies to the result of ==)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
if($image===false)
{
    echo '<div><img src="image source"></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed html in to php like this..

```
<?php if(!$condition) : ?>
 echo '<div><img src="image source"></div>'
<?php endif; ?>
```